# How to solve conflict between 2 libraries (NetCDF4 and geopandas)

Tags: python, conda, geopandas, netcdf4

I cannot have a python kernel that works with the libraries netcdf4 and geopandas together on Windows. When I add a library to my virtual environment, then I cannot add the other.

What I have done :

1. I built a new virtual environment :
   `conda create -n myenv`
2. I activated it : `conda activate myenv`
3. I installed geopandas: `conda install geopandas`, it works fine
4. I tried to install netCDF4: `conda install netCDF4`, and I got a looong error.

I have tried to install netCDF4 before geopandas but it did the same thing.

My error is pretty long (here are just the first lines) :

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package setuptools conflicts for:
pip -> setuptools
netcdf4 -> setuptools
attrs -> zope.interface -> setuptools
fiona -> setuptools
wheel -> setuptools
munch -> setuptools[version='>=17.1']
geopandas -> fiona -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
fiona -> munch -> setuptools[version='>=17.1']
setuptools

Package vc conflicts for:
libkml -> expat[version='>=2.2.5,<3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libspatialindex -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
proj -> sqlite[version='>=3.30.1,<4.0a0'] -> vc=9
rtree -> libspatialindex[version='>=1.9.3,<1.9.4.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
hdf4 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
libpq -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl-service -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libssh2 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
cligj -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libiconv -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a'] -> vc=9
munch -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
cfitsio -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
lz4-c -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
zlib -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
geos -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libtiff -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl_random -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
tbb -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
proj -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
xz -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
icu -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
curl -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
openssl -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libpng -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
postgresql -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libcurl -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
fiona -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
tk -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
hdf5 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
vc
mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.14,<2.0a0'] -> vc=9
pandas -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
python-dateutil -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
hdf4 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
pytz -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
geopandas -> fiona -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
freexl -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
libspatialite -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
sqlite -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libkml -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
libgdal -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
jpeg -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
krb5 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
tiledb -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
openjpeg -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
mkl_fft -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
netcdf4 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
openjpeg -> libpng[version='>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
click-plugins -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libboost -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
libxml2 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
click -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
wincertstore -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
bzip2 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
geotiff -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libnetcdf -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
numpy-base -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libboost -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
python=3.8 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
pyproj -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
kealib -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
gdal -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
tiledb -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
pcre -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
six -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
zstd -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
xerces-c -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
expat -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
attrs -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
shapely -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
```

about my conda/python versions :

```
conda version : 4.8.3
conda-build version : 3.18.11
python version : 3.7.6.final.0
```

According to you, what could I do ? (I have not found other libraries tha can do what I want)

Comment: It's always best to install all the packages at the same time. _I cannot have a python kernel that works with the libraries netcdf4 and geopandas together._ ..... _I have tried to install netCDF4 before geopandas but it did the same thing._ Which is it? Is geopandas really the issue?

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking time to answer. However I am not sure to understand your question

Comment: It's unclear whether you are using the conda-forge channel and whether you have `channel_priority` set to "strict". I was able to create an environment with both geopandas and netcdf4 on Windows 10 with no issues (with conda-forge and strict channel_priority).

Comment: @RO-ito Is the issue actually with netcdf4, or could it be something else, since geopandas fails to install regardless?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue try 'conda install -c conda-forge netcdf4'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).